# Print Data of only first row of database instead of whole table

Tags: c#, html, mysql, sql, asp.net

I need to output the data that's only on the first row, but it is printing all the data added to the database table. Here is the data:

[image: Thats the image of my database]

For example, It should print only "Not Very Nice" and the message of ID 27, but not the second row that has ID 28.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class feedback1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    string cons = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(cons);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into feedback(username,message) values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text +"')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

Here is the output..
[image]

This is the output page code..

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" GridLines="None">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" SortExpression="username" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="message" HeaderText="message" SortExpression="message" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [feedback]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Change the SelectCommand to SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [feedback]

Comment: I can not see the code using which you are selecting to printing data.

Comment: @Gaurav it's the line which starts with `<asp:SqlDataSource` - the query is right at the end

Comment: limit 1 ? .....

Comment: **Warning:** Your INSERT query is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using .NET. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a case of modifying your SQL-query:

Selecting the 1st row:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [feedback] LIMIT 1">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Selecting specific ID:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [feedback] WHERE [id] = REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_NUMBER">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

> *"Note: Not all database systems support the SELECT TOP clause. MySQL supports the LIMIT clause to select a limited number of records."*

Please see: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

## NOTE

Your program is vulnerable to SQL-injections. 
Please modify your input to sanitize your query before its executed.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cons);
    con.Open();
    string txtb1= TextBox1.Text,
           txtb2= TextBox2.Text;
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "select * from product where name = @name";
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into feedback(username,message) values('" + @txtb1 + "','" + @txtb2 +"')", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("txtb1", txtb1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("txtb2", txtb2);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Stop right there! ✋! This is the police  I hope you've [read up on the laws](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/protect-your-data-prevent-sql-injection/) around this block. You're in violation of penal code **404** - *Database Not Found!*

If you post another  sql-vulnerable  post again in this neighborhood

I'm gonna have to  arrest you

No ticket today

This is just a warning ⚠️ be careful next time

Comment: "TOP" is not possible with MySQL (which is what the question is tagged with). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: @ADyson You're correct, its even listed in the resource i provided.

Comment: I used your second code i.e. for ID and it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you always want that specific row with ID 27, or whether you just want the "first" row, whatever that happens be, you can write either

```
SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE id = 27
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM feedback LIMIT 1
```

respectively.

P.S. This is given using `MySQL` syntax, since that's what you tagged the question with. However, from your code I can see that you use a `SqlConnection` object to connect, which is only compatible with `Microsoft SQL Server`. If you're using SQL Server and not MySQL, then please change your question tags to mention the correct product. You would also need to alter the second query in my example above to `SELECT TOP 1 FROM feedback`, as `TOP` is used in SQL Server, whereas `LIMIT` achieves the same effect in `MySQL`.

Comment: There's no problem to add information to database but it should print only one row whichever I need!

Comment: yeah, i got confused by that also. Until OP changes the tags, i'll assume mysql.

Comment: @Yash my answer doesn't refer to adding anything. Are you replying to my comment above regarding SQL injection? In that comment I'm not saying that your INSERT doesn't work, what I'm saying is it's vulnerable to hackers. Visit the link I provided in the comment and you will start to understand why it's an issue. I  doubt you want people to be able to delete your data without permission, for example!

Comment: @Yash please also clarify to us whether you are using MySQL or SQL Server? Do you understand they are different database systems? As I mentioned, your question tag contradicts what appears to be in your code.

Comment: @Yash are you certain? If that's the reality then you will not be able to make a connection to your database using `SqlConnection` - that will work for `Microsoft SQL Server` only - see the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2). In .NET, for MySQL you have to use the [MySQL connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/) instead. I am thinking that maybe you don't actually know what tech you are using, which is not a good thing really. It should be very easy for you to check what you are really using